# Installing Ubuntu Studio 18.04 as a guest VM in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I installed several versions of Windows and Linux guest VMs in Virtualbox without relevant problems.
While attempting to install Ubuntu Studio 18.04 as a guest VM I see the installation or the guest VM hang,
Is there any known issue?
How should I confugure the VM in order to support Ubuntu Studio 18.04?
Regards
marius

Comment: You've provided little detail.  Did you verify your ISO was flawless?, that you have enough space for Ubuntu Studio (it contains loads more software needing larger space than most flavors). What did you see in logs?  Also be aware Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS release; so you'll need to add a PPA to get extended support as it's EOL (details well laid out in release notes)

Comment: https://ubuntustudio.org/2018/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-released/  https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/